# What is this strange kanji that looks a bit like 侍, but isn't?

Tags: kanji, abbreviations

Staying at a ryokan recently, I received some postcards with the following little poem:

[image]

What are the characters that I have highlighted in red? They look a bit like [侍]{さむらい}, but based on the context clearly aren't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this character is a fairly common *[ryakuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryakuji)* (abbreviated character) of the common honorific [御]{ご} *go-*, as in [御飯]{ごはん} *gohan*, so the full word is [御夢想]{ごむそう} *go-musou*, the name of [the hot spring where the ryokan was located](http://musouen.co.jp/about/index.html).  Another example [here](http://nihongodekiru.blog62.fc2.com/blog-date-201003-2.html).